# Patent Situation around Slicing CRC-32 Implementations

Tags: hash, crc32

In around 2006, Intel engineers came up with the idea of enlarging the CRC-32 look-up table in order to process 4 or 8 bytes at once (maybe the original idea was not their, but at least they have published a source code with the implementation that was up to 4 times faster than previous implementations with just one table of 256 elements of 32 bits). Their code is available on SourceForge at sourceforge.net/projects/slicing-by-8 , known as Slicing-by-8. Don't you know whether Slicing-by-8 etc. (Slicing-by-4, Slicing-by-16) is encumbered by any patent? There is such a big number of active patents on CRC and CRC32, and they are written in such a language that it is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done a patent search on this, so I don't know if the concept was ever patented. However I do know that the idea well precedes the Intel paper you mention. I first implemented it in zlib in version 1.2.0, which was published in March 2003. The approach was suggested to me by Rodney Brown in an email to gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org on April 19, 2002 (with no mention or hint of a patent). I don't know when he first came up with it, or if it was published even earlier by him or someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided to sourceforge states that the slice-by-8 is BSD licensed, so you can freely use it without worrying about patent infringement.

**UPDATE**

From the link withing the source code itself it's pretty clear to me that you are able to use this without issue, just include the copyright info like they say:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.html

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
>   "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
>   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
>   A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
>   HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
>   SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
>   LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
>   DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
>   THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
>   (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
>   OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Also https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/whitesource-blog/top-10-bsd-license-questions-answered/

> 9. Do the BSD Licenses grant patent rights?
>
> The BSD licenses don’t grant any patent rights. 
>   ...
>   The BSD
>   Licenses, on the other hand, just grant a copyright license. While
>   licensing your component, you will have to take care of the patents
>   yourself.

Ergo, Intel doesn't mention anything about patents in the source code, therefore it's highly unlikely that they are trying to trap people using their code, that they made freely available in the public domain.

And lastly, if someone else's patent did, or does, cover what Intel has released, if said patent came after 2004 (the initial date in the copyright), then that patent isn't valid against this code anyways; although it might take a lawyer to prove it.  But date disputes are usually pretty simple.

Comment: The BSD licence only cover copyright issues (how you may use the text of the computer program, as well as the compiled forms, etc) - it does not guarantee that there are no patents on the algorithms implemented by this code. For example, before GIF LZW patents expire, I could write source code that handles GIFs and distribute it under BSD licence, this did not mean that anybody who uses my code won't need to get a permission from the holder of the patent ("Unisys").

Comment: Thank you for the update. There are lots of CRC patents registered before 2004, unfortunately.